# Is it ok to connect two camunda instances to the same database?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, camunda

We are developing a spring boot application(generated with jhipster, with oauth) and we want to use camunda.

The camunda spring boot starter(with the process engine only) worked, however the we had problems with the other two starters(rest, web) in our current setup(although they work with a simple project like in the camunda examples).

We actually prefer using the embedded process engine like this, however, we would like the operational advantages of the camunda webapps.

The preferred solution we thought about was to connect to the same database another process engine(camunda standalone or springboot app with camunda web starter). This seems to be working in our tests.

The other solution would be to use camunda standalone and communicate via rest api, and subscribe to topics for service tasks.

Do you see any problems with the preferred solution?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's perfectly fine running two engines against same database. Just make sure to set `camunda.bpm.job-execution.enabled=false` in the other instance(if you don't want it to pick up and execute jobs)